# Creating header column and combining unequal length/value data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 24 data frames (one for each month over 2 years) that contain states in the rows and values in the columns as such:

```
        Group.1        x
1       Michigan 41.60000
2  New Hampshire 41.03333
3 North Carolina 45.33333
4          Texas 52.00000
```

```
         Group.1        x
1        Alabama 59.00000
2        Arizona 47.40000
3     California 37.00000
4       Delaware 44.92000
5        Florida 49.11125
6           Iowa 46.50000
7       Michigan 43.54000
8       Missouri 50.50000
9         Nevada 40.50000
10 New Hampshire 42.75000
11    New Mexico 44.35000
12     Tennessee 55.60000
13         Texas 49.33333
14          Utah 48.50000
15 West Virginia 66.00000
16     Wisconsin 45.28571
```

I want to make the first header column a list of all 51 states (D.C. included), and fill in the information from each of the remaining data frames into its appropriate row.  So the final product would be a data frame [51x24] with Columns ranging from January 2019, February 2019, ... , December 2020.  What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::full_join` (or base r merge) to join two data.frames and repeat this for all the dataframes.
Assuming you have all the 24 data.frames stored in a list

```
# create a dataframe with all state names in case
# some states are not present in any of the 24 dataframes 
all_states <- data.frame(Group.1 = c(state.name, "DC"))

# join all 24 data.frames one by one
Reduce(function(x,y) dplyr::full_join(x, y, by = "Group.1"), 
       df_list, 
       init = all_states
)
```

You will need to rename the columns to the given year-month if not already so in the data. Doing this before the join would be better.